# Unable to find my mail log file (looked for the path in 50-default.conf and rsyslog)

Tags: ubuntu, email, log-files

I am trying to send emails from my linode ubuntu server but I am unable to. So I had this test script set to log the errors by adding this right before mail()

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Now I am trying to look for my mail.log file and it's no where to be found on my server. I am a little confused for the correct path. Here's what the different files say ...

php.ini

```
    ;mail.log =
    ; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
    ;mail.log = syslog
```

50-default.conf

```
    # Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
    # it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
    #
    #mail.info          -/var/log/mail.info
    #mail.warn          -/var/log/mail.warn
    mail.err            /var/log/mail.err
```

rsyslog

```
    /var/log/mail.log
```

I have checked all the paths specified above and couldn't find the mail.log or mail.info files on my server. Even tried reading the syslog file but couldn't find any relevant information there.

I'd really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `php.ini`:

 `;mail.log =
 ;mail.log = syslog`

The `;` means that the row is commented out, and the first one `;mail.log =`usually means that the default is '' i.e. nothing. Try and comment out the syslog (to be)

`mail.log = syslog`

Then it should hopefully end up with one of the `/var/log/mail,*` logs based on the syslog configuration.

You might need to restart apache/php-fpm depending on how php is used on your host (I'm not familiar with Linode nor Ubuntu servers).

Comment: Doesn't "//" or "#" means it's commented in php?

Comment: Comment format depends on the file type, so for `.ini` files, ";" is often used as a comment, and I'm referring to the php.ini file in the above answer.

Comment: On a side note: it also depends on **how** PHP sends mail. You won't see any local mail log events if you send email over SMTP (to either a remote SMTP host or your you use your own server but it isn't running an SMTP server), nor when you use an API (such as sendgrid) ; typically you will only get syslog events from sendmail/postfix/exim when you use the php `mail` function that relies on the  [`sendmail_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Fredrik. So do I remove the first instance of ;mail.log and remove the ; at second instance, in the php.ini file, right?

Comment: @HBruijn, yeah I think it is sending through php mail function because I don't have any services like sendgrid or gsuite.

Comment: @FredrikLundhag, I have commented out mail.log = syslog as you asked and ran that script again, but there's no updates in my syslog file and nor there's any new log files in the log folder